# NHibernate multiple joined subclasses and duplicate column names using criteria

Tags: nhibernate, criteria, nhibernate-criteria, joined-subclass

Assume we have this entity structure:

```
Document
- DocumentA
- DocumentB
```

In base class Document we have fields **Id**, **Name**, **CreateDate**. In joined subclass DocumentA we have fields **Book**, **Pages**. And in DocumentB we have **Magazine**, **Pages**.

So the problem is when i try to get records with Criteria:

```
var prj = Projections.ProjectionList();
foreach (var col in selectColumns)
{
    prj.Add(Projections.Property(col), col);
}
criteria.SetProjection(prj).SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(entityType));
```

So if we have in **selectColumns** two **Pages** columns NHibernate will only select data from first one. In fact it even generates SQL query like this

```
SELECT top 15 
this_1_.Pages as y0_
, this_1_.Pages as y1_
, this_.CreationDate as y2_
, this_.CreationAuthor as y3_
, this_.Name as y4_
, this_.Id as y5_
FROM Document this_ 
left outer join DocumentA this_1_ on this_.Id=this_1_.Id 
left outer join DocumentB this_2_ on this_.Id=this_2_.Id
```

Does anyone know how to solve my problem using Criteria? BTW I do not have option to change this structure, in this system user can define his own classes and nested classes.

Comment: Why do you need a projection at all? Just return your documents...

Comment: Ok. Problem solved by rewriting some NHibernate code.